# kali linux amd64 live usb did not ask for user name and pswd

Tags: linux, usb

I am new to kali linux,installed it from kali.org,using live linux iso amd64,after booting from usb live it dont ask username and pswd it just takes to five options,linux(amd64),kali linux(forensics) and three others including graphic install,i am just wondering for beginners which one is best

it just takes me straight into kali linux amd64 and kali linux usb persistence and dont ask for any user name and pswd,is that the way it works

please help

Answer (score 0):

The Live USB (or Live CD) is a "read-only" version of the operation system used for testing. It allows you to try out the operation system before installing it. You will be restricted to make changes to the system (ex.: installing packages), and your hard drive will not be changed. There should be, on the desktop, an icon that allow you to actually install the system onto your hard drive, and you will be asked for an user name and password at that point, along with some other configurations. In the case of Kali, the install option is in the boot menu, [here](http://docs.kali.org/installation/kali-linux-hard-disk-install) is the official guide on installing Kali onto hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it doesn't , at least not here.

The screen you're just seeing is the selection screen. it gives you options to install it on your HDD or just open live session (optionally with persistence mode if you've configured it).

With a **Live** session you're able to use your OS without actually installing it. It's just for quick works (or hacks since it's *Kali*)

It will ask a password (sometimes not) after you select a live session (and after some loading) or after your installation. If It asks for a password when opening a live session the username is *root* and the password is *toor*. you'll know what to give if it asks after installation.

And finally as the site says **Kali is not for beginners**. there are a lot more Linux distro 's u can use as a beginner.